# Conda will not update

Tags: conda, updates, miniconda

I have miniconda3 installed. I keep getting this error, both in my base environment and custom environment(including when I run $ conda update -n base conda):

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.10.3
  latest version: 22.9.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda



# All requested packages already installed.
```

I see this error in any new install/ update I try to make in my conda environments. I also tried

```
 $ conda env update
```

and

```
$ conda update conda
```

and

```
$ conda update --prefix /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py27 miniconda
```

Comment: It would help to show `conda env list` (to check if there are multiple Conda installations) and add to the question body the output of `conda info`. Also, might be worth trying `conda install -n base 'conda>=22.9.0'`. Please be careful not to conflate "*warning*" and "*error*" - they are not interchangeable terms.

Comment: I do have multiple conda environments, not sure what you mean vs installation:                base*  /home/ubuntu/miniconda3
bs                       /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/bs
fastq-dl                 /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/fastq-dl
py27                     /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/py27
terra_gisaid             /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/terra_gisaid